# How can I add bulk attribute to attribute sets in Magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes, programmatically, attribute-set

Everyone,
How can I set attributes to attribute set in Magento 2 programmatically

Comment: You are looking for an extension or you want to do it programatically?

Comment: programmatically

Answer (score 1):

The **custom attribute** gets assigned to all the **attribute sets** or you want to assign it to **specific attribute set** only.

**Hope this will help you.**

```
$attribute_set_name = 'your attribute set name';
$group_name = 'your attribute group';
$attribute_code = 'your attribute code';

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

//-------------- add attribute to set and group
$attribute_set_id=$setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_name);
$attribute_group_id=$setup->getAttributeGroupId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, $group_name);
$attribute_id=$setup->getAttributeId('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
$setup->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId='catalog_product',$attribute_set_id, $attribute_group_id, $attribute_id);
```

Comment: I want to assign specific attributes set only ..